# Math font to match Helvetica

Tags: fonts, math-mode

Is there any package to change the math font (amsmath Computer Modern) to match the Helvetica font I am using as default in my document (`helvet` or `tgheros` package)?

<sup>(In the same way as `mathpazo` for Palatino math)</sup>

Comment: Try `arevmath` which is originally for Bitstream Vera.

Comment: `mathpazo` doesn't use a math palatino font. There exists only a commerical version of Palatino math. You can use `sansmath.sty`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `sansmath` package.

Credit to Herbert.

Answer (score 2):

MicroPress has designed the [HV Math](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/hvmath/hvmain.htm) fonts for which there's also LaTeX support via the [hvmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/hvmath) package. Note that the Type 1 version of HV Math is commercial, but there's a free bitmapped version with a resolution of 300 dpi.

EDIT: As Herbert pointed out, the commercial Type 1 version isn't available anymore.

Comment: that font is no more available. micropress-inc doesn't exists anymore!

Comment: @Herbert Using http://www.micropress-inc.com/demo.htm#hvmath, I was able to download what seems to be font plus support files. Or do you mean that the Type 1 fonts isn't available anymore?

Comment: yes, meant the commercial type 1 version. Same for Paltino and so on